# How to custom android button with onclick event

Tags: android

I'm trying to achieve a custom controller containing of various buttons in different shapes. The result should look similar like this, where every one piece is a different button. How I can achieve this with Android.
http://s2.postimg.org/4srzkvdll/2_2_02.jpg

and how to button not covered when other button pressed
http://s18.postimg.org/4hz26retl/Untitled_1.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399320/displaying-an-android-radial-menu

Comment: Isn't it a same as Circle Menu?

Comment: i don't think it same as Circle Menu, position of the button will make a button is hidden by other nodes when clicked. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Each button can be made from an ImageView using a selector drawable to set the states.
And then, to layout the imageviews in a cicular fashion, take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173012/android-layout-views-rotated-and-spaced-around-a-circle) as a guide.

Comment: these are buttons shaped one piece,  position of the button will make a button is hidden by other nodes when clicked. http://s18.postimg.org/4hz26retl/Untitled_1.png

Answer (score 0):

in xml layout

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/your_custom_button_from_drawable" />
```

in activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private Button buttonSignup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setWindowAnimations(1);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//xml layout
    buttonSignup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);
    buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.buttonSignup :
            doYourWork();
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }
}
private void doYourWork()
{
    //do your work here
}
}
```

Comment: I still do not know how to create these buttons according to your instructions. Thanks.