# Rotate text in Android pie chart

Tags: android

I would like to add a text in a pie chart, like in the attached image.

how can I calculate the x,y points in the path.cubicTo(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

[image: Rotated text in pie chart]

Comment: look at this link to draw the pie menu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173012/android-layout-views-rotated-and-spaced-around-a-circle

Answer (score 0):

I think using basic geometry functions `sin` and `cos` will help: A point on a circle P(x, y) can be expressed only depending on the angle. You just iterate through 45° pieces (360°/8 pieces = 45°)

The cosine of that angle will return a `x` value whereas the sine will return a `y` value. From there on, the rest of the coordinates can be calculated easily or at least in the same way.

Here's an image that illustrates this:

[image: circle]

([source](http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/pool/tuts/SelfDXD/DirectXGraphics/theorie/degkreis.gif))