# Programatically adding rotated TextViews around a circle in android (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I'm making a game. In the game, I would like to display player names around a circle as if they are sitting around a table. I'm using vertical Linear Layout as the table and Constraint Layout as the main layout. I'm trying to add the TextViews **programatically.**

I tried various solutions including calculating the positions of the player names with trigonometric functions and radius. I asked GPT a couple of times but it kept failing, either TextViews didn't get displayed or they stacked on each other in the middle of the table rather than being displayed around it.
I also tried the solution at [Android Layout views rotated and spaced around a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173012/android-layout-views-rotated-and-spaced-around-a-circle), but it didn't work.

```
package com.example.puzzlegame;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.graphics.Color; import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable; import android.os.Bundle; import android.util.Log; import android.view.Gravity; import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.ImageView; import android.widget.LinearLayout; import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    ArrayList\<Player\> players = Player.getPlayers();
    int numberOfPlayers = players.size();

    LinearLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
    tableLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_table);
    tableLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    // Calculate the angle between each player
    double angle = 2 \* Math.PI / numberOfPlayers;

    // Calculate the radius of the circular arrangement
    int radius = Math.min(tableLayout.getWidth(), tableLayout.getHeight()) / 2;

    // Clear any existing views in the tableLayout
    tableLayout.removeAllViews();

    // Add rotated TextViews for each player
    for (int i = 0; i \< numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        TextView playerNameTextView = new TextView(this);
        playerNameTextView.setText(players.get(i).getName());
        playerNameTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        playerNameTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        // Calculate the coordinates of the TextView based on the angle and radius
        int x = (int) (radius \* Math.sin(i \* angle));
        int y = (int) (radius \* Math.cos(i \* angle));
        params.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);

        playerNameTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
        tableLayout.addView(playerNameTextView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you use `Gravity.CENTER` at the same time as margins? I also don't understand why you need a `LinearLayout` if it's only used as a `FrameLayout`. And it also seems to me that x is confused with y.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib as a solution.

[https://github.com/ogaclejapan/ArcLayout](https://ArcLayout)

But you have to make some customisation. By defalut open the Arc view and set name of players around the center View.